# Compare more than 2 lists in R

Tags: r

I have been learning R programming language for a month and have some difficulties in lists and dataframes. I couldn’t figure out how to find the intersection between more than 2 lists.  I created four lists , which contain name, gender, age, 3 favorite movies , Support to UN, birth day and month of immediate family member :

```
x<- list("Corinna Neubach", "female", 24, list("Film1","Film2","Film3"), TRUE,list("31.05",  "19.12"))
z<- list("Yasmin Ritschl","female", 21, list("Film6","Film7","Film8"), TRUE, list("20.03", "10.12"))
a<- list("Stefan Braun", "male", 23, list("Film6","Film7","Film8"),TRUE,list("25.06", "15.12"))
y<- list("Melissa Okay", "female", 23, list("Film3","Film4","Film5"), TRUE,list("31.05", "10.12"))
```

I would like to check, if there is any shared birthday or names in the four lists.
First I wrote a code with „Reduce“, but it doesnt give the solution which I want to have.
Then, I have tried it with intersect but I think there should be a simplier way to do that

```
intersect(x[[6]],y[[6]])
intersect(x[1],y[1])
intersect(x[[6]],z[[6]])
intersect(x[1],z[1])
intersect(y[[6]],z[[6]])
intersect(y[1],z[1])
intersect(x[[6]],z[[6]])
intersect(x[1],z[1])
intersect(a[[6]],x[[6]])
intersect(a[1],x[1])
intersect(a[[6]],z[[6]])
intersect(a[1],z[1])
intersect(a[[6]],y[[6]])
intersect(a[1],y[1])
```

Comment: You'll find programming a lot easier if you use the right data structure in the first place. Here, you should store all your data in one data.frame. One column for the names, one for the genders, etc.

Comment: You are right but the question says: Create 4 lists in R containing this information: Name, gender etc.

Comment: I hope there is partial credit for doing the right thing. Good luck with your homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't think the single-person `list`s are the appropriate data structure for your task. They all have the same structure, this is an indicator that `data.frame` would be appropriate.

While `data.frame`s can contain lists inside their elements, your data suggests to translate the lists into tables of a normalized relational data base. You can map that to 2 or 3 `data.frame`s in R:

- the person data
- The 3 favourite films: if they are ordered (1st, 2nd, 3rd choice), you can use `data.frame` colums of the person table for that. If not, pull them into an extra `data.frame` with columns person and film.
- For the birth date of the relatives, I guess it is accidentally that your example data gives exactly 2 of them for each person. So pull that into another data.frame.

For hunting duplicates, have a look at `? table`.

---

edit: wrt. the requirement to build a `list`: `data.frame`s are `list`s in R:

```
> a <- data.frame (person = "John Doe", gender = "female")
> a
    person gender
1 John Doe female
> is.list (a)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: And if you use data frames and relational database organization of the frames, the library sqldf will most likely be useful for finding duplicates, and performing other SQL queries on your tables (eh data frames)